# How do I create a button in kotlin without xml?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I make a button without any XML? I tried XML but it did not work and it is "Old" I heard.

Comment: considering that there are thousands of app making use of xml, it most definitely isn't old. compose is an alternative and as of the time that you're writing isn't considered a direct replacement for xml's deprecation

Comment: You may want to take a look at this codelabs tutorial https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics

Comment: Welcome to the community. This however is considered a low quality question and would be downvoted quickly as it doesn't show anything you have tried to do or your current code. If your current situation is that you "tried XML but it did not work" and "it is old", it sounds like you need to find a beginners tutorial to teach you basic development. Otherwise update your question with the specifics, and remove the parts where you are asking for help and not to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, using XML is old but it's the standard way of defining views in Android. Nowadays exist alternatives to that such as Jetpack Compose which takes a more `React` style when declaring the GUI where you write `@Composable` functions that produce a UI. Quite nice.

In any case you can create the views yourself programatically but it's much more tedious, less maintainable and imho

---

With that said, from your activity you can create instances of any of the layouts that you would use in XML and then add more views into it:

```kotlin
class YourActivty: AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(...) {
    val frameLayout = FrameLayout(this).apply {
      // Configure the layout's properties
    }
    val button = AppCompatButton(this).apply {
       // Configure all button's properties 
    }
    frameLayout.addView(button)
    // Indicate your activity to use the framelayout as its content
    setContentView(frameLayout)
  }
}
```